# How do I use Serde to deserialize malformed JSON with True/False?

Tags: json, rust, serde, malformed

How can I deserialize the following malformed JSON using Rust's [serde](https://serde.rs/):

```
{
  "value": True
}
```

Using [this answer](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-serde-deserialize-with-for-option-s/12749/2), I tried the following solution:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.66
extern crate serde; // 1.0.66
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.21


use serde::de;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize)]
pub struct Foo {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_capitalized_bool")]
    pub bar: bool,
}

fn deserialize_capitalized_bool<'de, D>(
    deserializer: D,
) -> Result<bool, D::Error>
where
    D: de::Deserializer<'de>,
{
    struct CapitalizedBoolVisitor;

    impl<'de> de::Visitor<'de> for CapitalizedBoolVisitor {
        type Value = bool;

        fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            formatter.write_str("a True or False string")
        }

        fn visit_bytes<E>(self, v: &[u8]) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
        where
            E: de::Error,
        {
            if v == &['T' as u8, 'r' as u8, 'e' as u8] {
                Ok(true)
            } else if v
                == &['F' as u8, 'a' as u8, 'l' as u8, 's' as u8, 'e' as u8]
            {
                Ok(false)
            } else {
                unimplemented!();
            }
        }
    }

    deserializer.deserialize_any(CapitalizedBoolVisitor)
}

fn main() {
    let json = r#"{
        "bar": True
    }"#;

    let foo: Foo = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();

    let expected = Foo {
        bar: true
    };
    assert_eq!(foo, expected);
}
```

[runnable on the playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=93a59720b4b4cca1ed10552b8f4d4d64)

The problem, as far as I can tell, is that the input is not recognized as any correct type, so none of the [visitor APIs](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.Visitor.html) work here.

**UPDATE (2020-02-05)**:

Apparently this is not possible to solve with `serde_json` (one way would be to use a custom data format or to fork `serde_json` to add this functionality, as `serde_json` does not deal with invalid input, see the maintainer's [answer](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/616#issuecomment-582105254)).

A hacky solution, for anyone else having similar issues, is to replace the `True` and `False` instances in the raw response string to `true` and `false`. This is definitely not perfect, since if a string contains `True` or `False`, those would be replaced also, but it is perhaps an acceptable solution for specific use cases.

Comment: See also: [This same question on GitHub](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/616)

Comment: I haven't tried to run your example, but I think there's a typo in the line `if v == &['T' as u8, 'r' as u8, 'e' as u8] {` , as you're spelling "Tre" instead of "True". HTH.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can only deserialize input with a particular library if the input is in the data format that the library is for.

So for examples, if your input is not JSON, CBOR, MessagePack then you can't use serde_json, serde_cbor, or serde_messagepack to deserialize it.

The input you show appears to be YAML so you could try serde_yaml.

```
fn main() {
    let input = r#" {
                      "value": True
                    } "#;
    println!("{:#?}", serde_yaml::from_str::<serde_yaml::Value>(input).unwrap());
}
```

In other words the fact that data is invalid JSON tells you what library *not* to use — serde_json. To find the right library it's more useful to find a format that the data *is* valid in.

Comment: Last I checked that's not yaml. I don't think yaml allows the curly braces and I'm not sure about value being in quotes. I don't think yaml would be a suitable replacement.

Comment: The braces are a yaml flow-mapping node. https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/current.html#id933010

The quoted string is a yaml double quoted string key. https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/current.html#id904245

Comment: Try pasting the input into one of these YAML validators: https://onlineyamltools.com/validate-yaml https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ https://yamlchecker.com/ http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: In that case yaml might work for this test case, but would it be able to cover all of json without having serious drawbacks?

Comment: @Locke YAML is a superset of JSON. And dtolnay being the author of serde, I think it's safe to assume he knows what he is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid JSON, so you can't use `serde_json` to deserialize it.

Boolean constants in JSON are `true` and `false`, in lower-case.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no way to change the source format (I'm integrating against a third-party backend). Is there any possible workaround here other than manually deserializing the string with a hand roller JSON parser?